# Create reusable component for Angular Material Table and change its table header

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm currently working to create a reusable component for angular material table.
I've been manage to create a reusable component for the table.

I wanted to make the change the header in `*matHeaderCellDef` as it is defined:

```
columnHeader = ['studendID', 'fname', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

for example: change the `studentID` to Student ID and `fname` to First Name int the table header.

[image]

Now the problem is I can't manage to change the table header.

---

Please see the code that I have done so far.

**data-table.component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of columnHeader">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{tableData}}    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[tableData] }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnHeader"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnHeader;"></tr>
</table>
```

**data-table.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatTable} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tableData;
  @Input() columnHeader;
  
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.tableData);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

**employee.component.html**

```html
<app-data-table [tableData]="tableData" [columnHeader]="columnHeader"></app-data-table>
```

**employee.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableComponent } from '../shared/data-table/data-table.component';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  fname: string;
  studendID: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  columnHeader = ['studendID', 'fname', 'weight', 'symbol'];

  tableData: PeriodicElement[] = [
    {studendID: 1, fname: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
    {studendID: 2, fname: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
    {studendID: 3, fname: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
    {studendID: 4, fname: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
    {studendID: 5, fname: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
    {studendID: 6, fname: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
    {studendID: 7, fname: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
    {studendID: 8, fname: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
    {studendID: 9, fname: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
    {studendID: 10, fname: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  ];

}
```

---

Please see the 
[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resuable-datatable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.html) for the live code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this will help you! (You have to change the html to get the title)

**employee.component.ts**

Keep columnHeader as an object instead of an array. Or you can extend it to an array of objects to mention extra information like, pipes, render as html etc.,

```
columnHeader = {'studentID': 'ID', 'fname': 'First Name', 'lname': 'Last Name', 'weight': 'Weight', 'symbol': 'Code'};
```

**data-table.component.html**

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of objectKeys(columnHeader)">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{columnHeader[tableData]}}    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[tableData] }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="objectKeys(columnHeader)"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: objectKeys(columnHeader);"></tr>
```

**data-table.component.ts**

```
@Input() columnHeader;
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resuable-datatable-higlkc)

Comment: Thanks. I think using `Object.keys` solves my problem.

Comment: @davecar21 haw can I display last column data according to conditions like some data table needs "Edit", "Delete" button, but some of data tables, don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the simplest way.
You can define function to get header name like below

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of columnHeader">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{getHeader(tableData)}}    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[tableData] }}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

**TS:**

```
getHeader(tableData) {
    if(tableData === "studendID")
      return "Student ID";
    if(tableData === "fname")
      return "First Name";
    return tableData;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I got an idea. The problem is that I can't touch the code of the data-table.component. I wanted to pass parameters to the employee.component.

Comment: can't you even touch its HTML file? @davecar21

Answer (score 0):

Little enhancement over Shreenil's answer:

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of columnHeader">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> 
    {tableData, select, 
        studentid {Student ID}
        fname {First Name}
    }
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[tableData] }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

The fewer bindings you have in your template the more performant rendering you achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to achieve this is, create a map having `Map<field, properties>` and one of your property can be a label for each column like so you can have very dynamic control over field, its properties, and its behavior.

```
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of objectKeys(columnHeader)">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> 
      {{ myMap.get(tableData).label }}    
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
       {{element[tableData] }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="objectKeys(columnHeader)"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: objectKeys(columnHeader);"></tr>
```